# What does the sum notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, notation

What does the sum notation$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$$
mean?

Is the $n$ fixed or not?

Comment: Do you know what $\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ means? Do you know what $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n$ means?

Comment: I think this notation could be made a lot more clearer if one added that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. That way one can think that one can pick any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then evaluate the limit. This leads to the notion of this being a sequence (if it's a sequence) since by picking different $n$s one gets different elements of the sequence.

Comment: The notation and its meaning is completely standardized. There is only one thing it could mean, and that meaning is entirely prescribed by the conventional interpretation of the notation. The expression $\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ means $a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots$, whose value depends on $n$, call that value $c_n$. Then one takes the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n$.

Comment: I actually thought that as the most intuitive at first, but then thought, why is this really different from $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ where $n$ is any fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, e.g. n=1.

Comment: Where $n$ is fixed? Do you know what $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ means?

Comment: Since if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ converges, then surely any other $n$ will be a convergent series.

Comment: You have $n$ fixed if you can list the series $a_n+a_{n+1}+...$.

Comment: And the value of $a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots$ depends on $n$, which you vary if you're going to take the limit $n\to\infty$, that's how limits work. Maybe it will help if we simply use numbers. We are taking the limit of the sequence $$(a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots), \quad (a_2+a_3+\cdots), \quad (a_3+\cdots), \quad \cdots $$

Comment: So does the notion of the sequence come from the definition of limit for series? Since the limit for series says that the limit exists for all $n > N \in\mathbb{N}$. Then the sequence is all the series $a_n, n > N$.

Comment: Or does it come from the notion of $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking, how do we see that this is a sequence?

Comment: It's obviously a list of values. A sequence. Just look: $$(a_1+a_2+\cdots), \quad (a_2+a_3+\cdots), \quad (a_3+\cdots), \quad \cdots $$ It has a first value, a second value, a third value, and so on. That's a sequence!

Comment: Yeah, but from the original notation in the question. I believe the sequence is from the definition of limits for series. The definition says: Let $(a_n)$ be a series. The limit $a$ for the series exists, if $\forall n > N\space|a_n - a| < \epsilon, \epsilon>0$. That clearly reads that one evaluates the limit at every series ($a_n+a_{n+1}+...$), $n > N$.

Comment: What does "evaluate the limit at every series" mean? When talking about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n$, does it make sense to talk about "evaluating the limit at every $c_n$"?

Comment: It means that one fixes a $n=N$, then evaluates the limit of $(a_n+a_{n+1}+...)$. Then shifts the $n$ by one and evaluates the limit of $(a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+...)$. Then $(a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}+...)$. Since the definition of limit for series says to evaluate $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. $(a_n)$ is a series, inside the $|a_n - a|$? So one is evaluating the limits $|a_n - a|, |a_{n+1} - a|, |a_{n+2} - a|, ...$

Comment: For $n$ fixed, $a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots$ is a constant, so it doesn't make sense to take its limit. Obviously you might *mean* "take the limit $a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_m$ as $m\to\infty$," but that's already taken care of in the notation $a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots$. Use words correctly so you can communicate with and understand others. Everyone here has already told you everything you need to know in plain and clear language.

Comment: Well does Steven Gregory's answer then make sense? The limit of a sequence of series where every element of sequence is a constant? So the limit is then what?

Comment: Yes Steven's answer makes sense. That's what the notation means. *You* should *know* that's what the notation means, just by reading it. Assuming $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ is convergent to begin with, the limit will happen to be $0$, which can be proved.

Comment: Can you link to the definition of this notation somewhere? Because I just can't see what makes it a sequence?

Comment: $\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ is a value that depends on $n$. I've already told you this. A sequence by definition is a function of a natural number $n$, and $c_n:=\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ is certainly such a function.

Comment: What says that one should evaluate for all $n$? I.e. by shifting the lower bound?

Comment: The value depends on $n$, i.e. it's a function of $n$. Whenever you see $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ in front of an expression whose value depends on $n$ ... you should know what it means. Nobody ever writes $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ while also assuming $n$ is a fixed constant.

Comment: Ok so this is a definition of limits for $sequences$. I was viewing the definition for $series$. Now it makes sense.

Comment: Limits are always for sequences (or functions more generally). One doesn't "take a limit of a series," one evaluates a series by computing the limit of the *sequence* of its partial sums. Again, language. Always, whenever you see $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n$, that means take the limit of the sequence $c_1,c_2,c_3,\cdots$ so in particular $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ means take the limit of the sequence $$(\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j), \quad (\sum_{j=2}^\infty a_j), \quad (\sum_{j=3}^\infty a_j), \quad \cdots$$

Comment: It is confusing. One can say that a series converges, but also that a limit of that series (or sequence) converges. Or I guess series converges means "the limit of the sequence taken from the series" converges.

Comment: Sure, we use the terms converges and diverges to refer to both sequences and series. But we **never** write $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n$ when we mean to evaluate the series $c_1+c_2+\cdots$ and we **never** write $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ when we mean the limit of the sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$.

Comment: Yeah, now it's clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the limit of the sequence

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=2}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=3}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=4}^\infty a_j,\;
  \sum_{j=5}^\infty a_j,\;
   \cdots
$$

My first guess would be, if   $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ exists, then your answer has to be $0$.

For example
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} =
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{2^n} =
  0
$$

THEOREM. If
$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ exists, then
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j = 0$

PROOF. For convenience, let $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j = L$. Then, since the limit exists,

$L = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j + \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$

Now let $n \to \infty$. Then $L = L + \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j = 0$.

Comment: And the limit of that sequence is the sum of the limits of the individual sequences?

Comment: @mavavilj No, the limit of the limits of the individual sequences is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$

Comment: Which is what in the individual series notation? E.g. if one wanted to display the existence of that limit and one knows only that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ converges.

Comment: Doesn't sequence mean that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j+\;
  \sum_{j=2}^\infty a_j+\;
  \sum_{j=3}^\infty a_j+\;
  \sum_{j=4}^\infty a_j+\;
  \sum_{j=5}^\infty a_j+\;
   \cdots
$ is a sequence?

Comment: @mavavilj. No, you are confusion sequences and series.

Comment: So this is a sequence of series?

Comment: @mavavilj Comments need to have a minimum number of characters, so I had to be sort of verbose just to say "Yes".

Comment: Why do you call that proof "informal"?

Comment: Because $L = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j + \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ needs to be justified.

Comment: Is that not a basic property of sums? $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j + \sum_{j=n}^\infty a_j$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Or $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j = \sum_{j=0}^m a_j + \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{j+m+1}$, as given here (under "Infinite summation"): http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/

Comment: @mavavilj algebraic properties may fail when dealing with limits.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret it as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{j = n}^m a_j$$

Inside the two limits, both $n$ and $m$ are fixed.You then take the two limits on the expression found.

For example, you will arrive at an expression like $\sum_{j = n}^m a_j = \frac 1m + \frac {2n^2 + 1}{4n^2} - 1$ (notice how it depends only on $n$ and $m$).

Then you take both limits to find the result (in this case $-1/2$)

Comment: Isn't that a Cauchy series then?

Comment: @mavavilj I edited, maybe it's more clear.. I don't see the link with cauchy series

Comment: I think this is the only reasonable interpretation since it follows the standard definition.

Comment: Maybe the Cauchy series connection becomes more clear, if we first assume that  $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ is a convergent series $<=>$ $\lim_{j\to\infty}  a_j = 0$?

Comment: I've also seen it defined as: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=j}^j \alpha_j$, in which case if $\alpha_n$ converges, it would be the limit of the sequence, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n$.